# Connect database cell to text from another database cell

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect cell A in my database to a specific word in a line of text in cell B.
So for example,

Cell B has the following text in it:

"Hi there,
I want this (cell A) because I need this for my project."

Cell A has te following text in it:
"to work"

So on my website it will say:
"Hi there,
I want this to work because I need this for my project."

I'm working with phpmyadmin where these cells are stored.
The text is published on my website.

I've tried to do this with php in my database.
But phpmyadmin doesn't recognize php apparently.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is so-named because the tool itself is *written* in PHP. It can only process SQL commands, not PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Is it possible to code this in SQL commands?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried some things. Know how to code. Can't find anything online about this, spend a few hours on that. I can write my question in code, but the question is if somebody knows a way to do this because it doesn't work my way. waist of time to write my code, because there must be another way. I've written this in php, but apparently that doesn't work. thanks for your negative vote....

Answer (score 0):

i will demonstrate:

```html
CREATE TABLE t1` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CellA` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `CellB` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `t1` (`CellA`, `CellB`) VALUES ('to work ', 'Hi there, I want this');

SELECT concat(CellB, ' ', CellA, ' ', 'because I need this for my project.') from t1
```